# Bluebird promise resolve in express route

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I have an simple REST application and I want to read files in my directory and send them back to frontend. There's code I'm using:

```
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'))
const router = require('express').Router()

router.get('/list', async (req, res, next) => {
  const files = await fs.readdirAsync('presentations')
  res.json(files)
})
```

The problem is: my frontend receive 'Promise', but if I try to debug it shows me that `files` is an array.
I've tried not to use async/await syntax like that:

```
router.get('/list', (req, res, next) => {
  fs.readdirAsync('presentations')
    .then(files => {
      res.json(files)
    })
})
```

But result was the same: frontend still get `Promise`.

UPD: Problem was with frontend `axios` instance. It didn't resolve promise, so `await` for results solved a problem.

Comment: So, there are three parts. Reading, storing and sending.

Here's the reading part:

Comment: What do you mean by "frontend"? And what exactly do you get there?

Comment: @Bergi, Like I said, there's REST node.js backend. It's API. I send request to this backed and got response. I've made frontend on `Nuxt` and using `axios` to get data from my server (backend).

Comment: OK. So what is the problem? Axios will return a promise for your array when making a request. Can you please post the code that does not behave as expected, including its sample output?

Answer (score 0):

So, there are three parts. Reading, storing and sending.

Here's the reading part:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function readFiles(dirname, onFileContent, onError) {
  fs.readdir(dirname, function(err, filenames) {
    if (err) {
      onError(err);
      return;
    }
        onFileContent(filename);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Here's the storing part:

```
var data = {};
readFiles('dirname/', function(filename) {
  data[filename] = filname;
}, function(err) {
  throw err;
});
```

The sending part is up to you. You may want to send them one by one or after reading completion.

If you want to send files after reading completion you should either use sync versions of fs functions or use promises. Async callbacks is not a good style.

Comment: First of all, I don't need file content, just names, that's why I'm using `readdir`. Second thing is I'm using `Promises`. If there's thousand of files server will not respond untill read all of them and send response back.

Comment: I am also using the _readdir_ if had went though the code. Don't use the second part of the code if you don't want to read file.In first part itself you will get the files names